# Custom Page Templates

Tags: page-template

I am trying to find the feature to add a page template. I am adding an archive but when I go into pages->Add New-> I get no option in the sidebar to use the existing archives.php file I want to use. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`archives.php` is a template file that WordPress will use by default (if it exists). If you want to create a custom page template you need to create a new template file in your theme. You can read all about it [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates), but I'll provide an example below. Put this at the top of your new file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Your page template name goes here.
*/
?>
```

Then follow it with the custom code you need to display your data.

Then, when creating a new page that you would like to use the above template, you will see a drop-down list on the right that lists all the names of page templates you have in your theme.

Comment: I already have code similar to this in my style.css file. I created a theme from scratch and applied my CSS to it. i Created a custom archives.php file yet it doesn't display in the dashboard to allow me to select it as a template

Comment: +1 See also: [the Codex entry for custom Page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates).

Comment: "*I already have code similar to this in my style.css file.*" - It's not what's in your `style.css` file that matters, but rather the phpDoc header in **`archives.php`**.

Comment: The above code does not go in your stylesheet, it HAS to go at the top of your custom page template. Archives.php is a file name that is reserved by WordPress. If you want to use that same file, simply rename page-archives.php and it should work.

Comment: Actually, `archives.php` is *not* reserved; that would be `archive.php`. Though, I would still recommend using something like `template-archives.php` as your custom Page template file name. (I would *not* use `page-archives.php`, as `page-{slug}.php` *is* reserved by the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display).

Comment: I thought it had to be named archives.php. Been following a few tutorials to get to grips with WordPress as I am use to coding things from scratch. You were right putting that in the header worked. Thanks. Just as a side thought can you recommend any good WordPress tutorials that are accurate (some leave out a lot of detail or are version specific even the ones on wordpress.org :-/) Thanks again!

Comment: @ChipBennett - you are correct, I always forget that 'archives.php' is an optional template file. And for the use of template-archives over page-archives, you taught me something new :)

Comment: I would suggest [Digging Into WordPress](http://digwp.com/book/). Great read for WordPress beginners who have a lot of questions. Otherwise, just keep asking away and we'll do our best to answer you.

Comment: "*Just as a side thought can you recommend any good WordPress tutorials that are accurate*" - I would always recommend starting with the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org).